# parsing # in rails uris

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

i am getting  the following url information and need to parse it within rails. i already checked request and params but it is not there.

the "#" character seems to f*ck up things.

here's the url:

```
http://foo.bar.me/whoo#access_token=131268096888809%7C2.5BRBl_qt4xJ08n88ycbpZg__.3600.1276880400-100001151606930%7C0kJ1K-qoGBbDoGbLx6s4z5UEaxM.
```

thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Please be more explicit. How are you receiving this URL? What code are you using? What exactly is going wrong? etc etc... (also, no need for profanity...)

Comment: i am trying to create an oauth2 authentication for a facebook app as described in http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/ -- i am getting redirected as outlined but cannot access the token, since it is behind the #

Comment: if you get this URL from wordpress, it's a wordpress issue. Because not render access_token like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to access the part after the '#' character as the browser doesn't send it to the server. You can use it on the client side with javascript though.

It seems that you're trying to use the [javascript based authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/javascript) which is not what you really want.

I didn't have any problems using this [oauth2](http://github.com/intridea/oauth2) library. Then you only need to check for `params[:code]` within your callback action.

**UPDATE:**

This is a simplified version of the code I used in my experiments with the new facebook graph API:

```
# Accessible as facebook_url:
# routes.rb: map.facebook '/facebook', :controller => 'facebook', :action => 'index'
def index
  oauth2 = OAuth2::Client.new(FB_API_KEY, FB_API_SECRET, :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com')

  if current_user.facebook_token
    # The user is already authenticated
    fb = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(oauth2, current_user.facebook_sid)
    result = JSON.parse(fb.get('/me'))
  elsif params[:code]
    # Here we get the access token from facebook
    fb = oauth2.web_server.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => facebook_url)
    result = JSON.parse(fb.get('/me'))
    current_user.facebook_id = result["id"]
    current_user.facebook_token = fb.token.to_s
    current_user.save
  else
    # The user is visiting this page for the first time. We redirect him to facebook
    redirect_to oauth2.web_server.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => facebook_url, :scope => 'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access')
  end
end
```

You don't really need anything else for it to work.

Comment: great answer, thanks a lot! to clarify things: it looks like apache mod_rewrite strips out the "#".

Comment: It is not stripped by mod_rewrite, #-part never gets to the server, it is interpreted solely by client's browser.